# Cambiar el valor de una celda bajo la condicion de otra en filas especificas apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

**SITUACION**

Tengo una matriz donde la columna "11" (K) en cada fila, posee (RM o REGION/PERIFERIA) nunca ambas juntas. Luego en las columnas "14 (INSUMOS)" y "15 (SEGURO)" hay diferentes valores, donde en cada fila que posea valor "RM", debo cambiar los valores de dichas columnas a "0".

**Objetivo**

Lo que busco es que el código encuentre cada fila donde se encuentre el valor "RM" y borre los valores de las columnas "14" y "15".

[image]

**PROBLEMA**

En el código, encuentra las filas donde dice "RM" en la columna "11" pero cuando le digo setvalue "0" en las columnas 14 y 15, correspondiente a esas filas, borra otras que no corresponden.

[image]

**CODIGO**

```
function depuracionRM() {

var freeskinHoja = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1odRp4yq1N76E9JY89Zu3w7Cugqdt_GaBljpefVgLDjw/edit?usp=sharing");
var destinoFSK = freeskinHoja.getSheetByName("FREESKIN");

var inRange = destinoFSK.getRange(2, 11, destinoFSK.getLastRow(), 5).getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < inRange.length; i++) {
  var precio0 = inRange[i][0];
  if(precio0 == "RM"){
    destinoFSK.getRange(i,14).setValue(" ");
    destinoFSK.getRange(i,15).setValue(" ");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se trata de un problema con los índices. Mientras que JavaScript usa índices base 0, el método `Sheet.getRange` del servicio de hoja de cálculo de Google (SpreadsheetApp) usa índices base 1.

Para resolver el problema de manera muy simple cambia

```
destinoFSK.getRange(i,14).setValue(" ");
destinoFSK.getRange(i,15).setValue(" ");
```

por

```
destinoFSK.getRange(i + 1,14).setValue(" ");
destinoFSK.getRange(i + 1,15).setValue(" ");
```

Nota:

El script tiene varios problemas. A continuación algunos de ellos:

1. El usar Sheet.getRange dentro de un bucle es muy ineficiente, por lo que Google recomienda el uso de operaciones por lotes.
2. El agregar una espacio en blanco no cambia el valor a 0, en lugar de `" "` deberías poner `0` o si no quieres mostrar ningún valor usa `""` (cadena de texto vacía).

Comment: Lo pude resolver con eso, muchas gracias.